# Android Notifications - Create notification if requirements are met

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm creating an app and have become a bit stuck as I haven't tried this before

What I want is even if the app is not running a service will every day loop through a table in my database and retrieve a certain column which has a date stored within, get todays date, then compare the two dates to see if they are equal / todays date is more than the retrieved date.

If the above condition is met I then want the service to create a notification so that the user will know that the requirement has been made

However I have very little knowledge on creating a service within my application and also how to do notifications

Any help / tutorials would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create local notification?

Comment: I believe so yes, I only want a notification for that specific person, not everyone who has the app

Comment: No I mean. Does that notification get generated from the server or the condition will be checked within phone and notified to user?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, condition will be checked within phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the below link, It has example of notifying the user after 15 seconds. After 15 seconds, a call to BroadcastReceiver will be given, there you need to check the condition, if the condition satisfies, then notify the user and again set the alarm after lets say 1 hour

[WebReference(Example)](http://www.singhajit.com/schedule-local-notification-in-android/)

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 There You need to check the logic
```

}